# Replace indexes with values using VelocityTemplate

Tags: java, replace, velocity

I'm a newbee to java Velocity Templates. I'm having a String that will be having some numeric placeholders/variables. I need to replace them with its corresponding values. How could I achieve this in java?

Code sample:

```
String templateString = "Replacing $0 with its value.";
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("0", "Sample value");

StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
Velocity.evaluate(context, output, "log or null", templateString);

System.out.println("output: " + output);
```

Above code didn't replace the $0 variable with "**Sample value**", but it worked when I had a string as the placeholder/variable instead of $0. Are there any workarounds to replace the $0 with its value? Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no workaround in Velocity itself: the parser doesn't allow reference names to start with numbers.

So you'll have to pre-process the templates, with something like:

```
templateString = templateString.replaceAll("\\$(\\d+)","\\$_$1");
context.put("_0", "Sample value");
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Claude. This solution worked for me. 
And I just need to know whether this could have any performance related issues when the content become larger and also need know whether this way is not violating any coding standards.

Comment: Yes, there are obviously performance concerns, and it remains a bit hackish, for sure...